# Creating database for climate data with MySQL

Tags: mysql, esri-grid-format

I'm working on a project using climate data and MySQL. Before I start to work, what's your advice on the best way to complete this task.

I plan on using the following workflow:

> 1. Analyse the climate-data, creating a mysql database-schema that could hold the data. (all tables should use UTF-8 as charset).
> 2. Download all the raw-data from worldclim.org, using the 30 arc-seconds (~1 km) resolution.
> 3. Import the data. Providing a dump

I have already downloaded the data for Min.Temperature, and it looks like this when I open one of the folders

[image]

The data is in .adf format: how can I insert that format into MySQL?

Also, what do you think is the best way to organize the database in MySQL for that kind of data?

I explored and found out that is option in AutoCAD Map 3D (FDO) where I can insert shapefiles in MySQL. Maybe then is the best way to convert coverages to shapefiles and then in Autocad Map 3D to MySQL?

---

I need to use MySQL. So I'll download . bil files. gissolved said I can save it in a blob field in my database and KevinMayall said I should convert it to ASCII and then to MySQL. These are raster files. What is the best way to import .bil files to database then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That whole folder is an ARC/INFO coverage.  You actually need to keep the entire tmin folder intact, including the info subfolder.  You're only going to be able to read these with ESRI software.

You should instead download worldclim.org's generic grid file format (.bil).  You can probably use GDAL or GRASS to convert it to ascii, and then to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The data is in [Esri Grid format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000w000000).

The VAT (vat.adf) gives away that it is not a coverage.

You will need to use software that can read/import that.